# VBA for each loop with 64K+ ListRows (ouf of memory)

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, excel-tables, listobject

I'm running a VBA `for each` loop through an Excel table (Listobject) which checks if a file exists based on a given path. My table has expanded though and has 68K Listrows. After launching the code, it quickly gives an error `Run-time-error '7': Out of memory`

It runs OK with 63K lines (done within 5 minutes) and based on googling there appears to be something called "64K segment boundary". Is this what's affecting my code to run since it really feels like it buffers the row count at first and then bounces back w/o starting to actually run anything. Is there an easy workaround for this without the need to split up my dataset into multiple batches? Frankly, I was quite surprised that 64K limits would still be a thing in Excel in 2021.

Running it on 64bit Excel 2019, but no luck with Office365 either.

```
Sub CheckFiles()

Dim Headers As ListObject
Dim lstrw As ListRow

Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileExists As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
Set Headers = ws.ListObjects("Import")

    For Each lstrw In Headers.ListRows
    
        strFileName = lstrw.Range(7)
        strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
        
        If strFileExists = "" Then
        lstrw.Range(4) = "not found"
        Else
        lstrw.Range(4) = "exists"
        End If
    
    Next lstrw

Set ws = Nothing
Set Headers = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Read the desired data into an array, process the array with the loop and then write the array with the result back to the cells. This should run **much** faster when using arrays. Each read and write action comes with a lot of overhead. If you use arrays you have only one read action in the beginning and one write action in the end. Instead of one of those for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you use a regular range and not a listobject?

Comment: Just did a test: Can confirm the behavior. Changing to a regular `for`-loop (`for i=1 to list.ListRows.Count`) works without any problem, iterating over 70k rows within 3 seconds.

Comment: @FunThomas now that's interesting, because normally `For Each...Next` over an object collection is *orders of magnitude* faster than a `For...Next` loop. Could there be a memory leak bug in the Excel `ListObject` API?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The error comes instantly, before entering the loop for the first iteration. I assume that VBA tries to create some kind of array internally but it's limit is 64k and it throws an error - out of memory was the closest the VBA programmer could think about. Do you have any experience with other for-each loop iterating over > 64k items?

Comment: Okay, Collections and Dictionaries don't have that limit (even when using objects as key)

Comment: `For Each...Next` uses an enumerator mechanism that yields one object at a time... looks like an implementation bug in the `ListRows` collection.

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: For Each lstrw In Headers.ListRows throws the error

Comment: Just confirming that the error occurs when there is more than `65534` list rows i.e. more than `65535` total rows (including the header row). That `(256 * 256 - 1 (or - 2))` is obviously a limitation (I'm using `Windows 10 64bit Office 2019 64bit`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoid Accessing the Worksheet

- Since you cannot avoid looping, you better do it in the computer's memory, i.e. rather through the elements of an array than through the cells of a range.
- The code is still slow, about 10s for 200k rows on my machine, but that's because of `Dir`.
- Note how easy (one line only, when the range contains more than one cell) and how fast (a split second) it is to write (copy) a range to an array (`Data = rg.Value`) and write (copy) the array back to a range (`rg.Value = Data`).
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CheckFiles()

    Const wsName As String = "Import" ' Worksheet Name
    Const tblName As String = "Import" ' Table Name
    Const cCol As Long = 7 ' Criteria Column
    Const dCol As Long = 4 ' Destination Column

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim Headers As ListObject: Set Headers = ws.ListObjects(tblName)

    Dim Data As Variant ' Data Array
    With Headers.ListColumns(cCol).DataBodyRange
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim r As Long ' Array Row Counter (DataBodyRange Row Counter)
    Dim FileName As String ' File Name Retrieved by Dir
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        FileName = Dir(CStr(Data(r, 1)))
        If Len(FileName) = 0 Then
            Data(r, 1) = "not found"
        Else
            Data(r, 1) = "exists"
        End If
    Next r
    
    Headers.ListColumns(dCol).DataBodyRange.Value = Data

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all! A few takeaways. While obviously trying to write as efficient code as possible, any reasonable performance here is acceptable. With that said, `for each` loop took approx 5 minutes to run with 63K lines, meawhile it was done in about 15 seconds by the code I accepted as an answer by @VBasic2008 - without capacity problems either.

The only problem I had with this particular code was it being somewhat new approach for me, so possibly building on it in the future needs some dedication in looking deeper into it - but it sure looks efficient. I also put together a regular `for ... to` loop which also didn't run into problems with 68K lines and would steer between rows and columns with `offset` function.

Clearly faster than `for each` as @Pᴇʜ suggested but took approx 2x as long as the array method (30 seconds or so).

```
Sub CheckFiles_2()

Dim strFileName, strFileExists As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Headers As ListObject
Dim result As String
Dim counter, RowCount As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
Set Headers = ws.ListObjects("Import")

RowCount = Headers.ListRows.Count

For counter = 1 To RowCount

strFileName = Range("anchorCell").Offset(counter, 3)

        strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
        
        If strFileExists = "" Then
        result = "not found"
        Else
        result = "exists"
        End If

Range("anchorCell").Offset(counter, 0) = result

Next counter

Set ws = Nothing
Set Headers = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Unless there was a comment now deleted,  Pᴇʜ' s comment is explaining why using arrays is faster: the range is read once and written once hence the worksheet is accessed only twice (with more data of course) while looping through a range reads and writes the data for each row once (e.g. accesses the worksheet give or take 130,000 times). When using objects and you use a `For...Next` loop, it is probably always possible to write the code using a `For Each...Next` loop which is supposed to be faster. I'll add such a solution to my answer tomorrow, so you can compare it for yourself.